# Dask map_partitions meta when using lambda function to add column

Tags: python, pandas, apply, dask, dask-distributed

I am using `Dask` to apply a function `myfunc` that adds two new columns `new_col_1` and `new_col_2` to my Dask dataframe `data`. This function uses two columns `a1` and `a2` for computing the new columns.

```
ddata[['new_col_1', 'new_col_2']] = ddata.map_partitions(
lambda df: df.apply((lambda row: myfunc(row['a1'], row['a2'])), axis=1, 
                    result_type="expand")).compute()
```

This gives the following error:

```
ValueError: Metadata inference failed in `lambda`.

You have supplied a custom function and Dask is unable to  determine the type of output that that function returns. 

To resolve this please provide a meta= keyword.
```

How can I provide the `meta` keyword for this scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`meta` can be provided via kwarg to `.map_partitions`:

```py
some_result = dask_df.map_partitions(some_func, meta=expected_df)
```

`expected_df` could be specified manually, or alternatively you could compute it explicitly on a small sample of data (in which case it will be a `pandas` dataframe).

There are more details in the [docs](https://docs.dask.org/en/stable/dataframe-design.html).

Comment: The function `myfunc` returns two variables which are added as columns `new_col_1` and `new_col_2`, these can be string or JSON. Since the function does not return a `DataFrame` how do I specify `meta`?

Comment: Ah, true, meta is more flexible that just dataframes. I guess in your case it would have t o be a tuple of series (that are each a string or json).

Answer (score 1):

Sultan's answer is perfect about using `meta`. :)

You can also avoid using `map_partitions` here because Dask implements `apply`, which calls `map_partitions` internally:

```py
import json
import pandas as pd
import dask.dataframe as dd

df = pd.DataFrame({'x': range(1,5),
                   'y': range(6,10),
                  }).astype('str')

ddf = dd.from_pandas(df, npartitions=2)

def myfunc(x):
    s = "string: " + x[0]
    j = json.dumps({'json': x[1]})
    return [s, j]

ddf[['new_col_1', 'new_col_2']] = ddf.apply(myfunc, axis=1, result_type="expand", meta={0: 'object', 1: 'object'})

ddf.compute()

# Output of ddf.compute():
#
#    x  y  new_col_1      new_col_2
# 0  1  6  string: 1  {"json": "6"}
# 1  2  7  string: 2  {"json": "7"}
# 2  3  8  string: 3  {"json": "8"}
# 3  4  9  string: 4  {"json": "9"}
```

Also, in your code snippet, calling `.compute()` will create a pandas DataFrame, and hence, you'll get an error if you assign it to a Dask DataFrame (`ddata`). I'd suggest calling `compute` on `ddata` after assignment.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I can use `apply`.

Comment: When I use `ddf.apply` directly without using `map_partitions` and then call `compute`, is there a way to skip those rows that may generate any exceptions?

Comment: I don't think there's anything dask-specific for this, but maybe you can do a check in the function (`myfunc`) to make sure it'll work correctly? Also, it's probably worth asking a new question?